# Getting Window focus in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus

I need to identify when google chrome browser get focused. And specifically the browser tab in which my page is loaded.

Scenario:
I have a page opened in Google Chrome browser. Whenever the window ( corresponding browser tab) gets focused (mouse click/keyboard navigation) I need to invoke an event in javascript.

[I have tried addEventListener and attaching 'focus' event, but it fires more than once when focusing the window. And not firing when clicking on address bar of browser.]

Please help. Any hint would be appreciable.

Thanks,
Ani

Comment: are u gonna write the markup for that page? if not, u can try Selenium webdriver- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: I have markup for the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to get notified when the the address bar is focused, you can only do that based on the document itself. That means you should do indeed bind the focus event of your window.

Since the multi-fire is a problem for you, you need to consider throttling your calls. See this article for reference: http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation

Btw, underscore.js is a pretty nifty library and has methods like "debounce", "throttle", "delay", that can help you solve your multi-fire problem: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Hi Timothée Groleau, That was pretty good suggestion to handle multi-fire problem and much appreciated the help. In my case, I need a complete focus capture event to fired whenever the Chrome window tab get focused (clicking address bar, tool bar, window document etc). Is there any executable I can try like ActiveX in Internet Explorer which captures the window (browser) focus..? (Using like NPAPI, using plugin,extension or something else). Please bear with me and once again thanks for your help.